# Best way to find number of account within certain value ranges

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, ssms

I am having trouble what would be the best/most efficient way to find all accounts that fall within a certain value range without having 20 different selects.

So for example I need to find the following:

```
Account Value    Number of plans     average value
$100-$10000      
$11000-$15000
$16000-$20000
$21000-$30000
$30000+
```

So right now my query is basically this for every value range:

```
    SELECT COUNT (acct) AS 'Number of Plans'
     , AVG (Value) AS 'Average Value'
   FROM #RT1
  WHERE Value
        BETWEEN 0 AND 249999.99
        AND InstaCode = 'S'
```

and there are three different charts that needs to be populated in SSRS. The only way I can figure it out is writing 15 different select statements but i feel there should be an easier and more effective way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Please see below and let me know if that works

Comment: trying it now thanks

Comment: I dont see how that fixes my problem though. Even then i am stilling going to need to have 15 different selects

Comment: no its all one select- ill add more - see updated - whats wrong with that?

Comment: Okay i see thank you!

Comment: okay so it works partly. I need the count of each group as well. Not just the total. So i need total acct for 0-2499999 and 2500000-300000

Comment: OK I added the conditional aggregation to the count portions as well - please see updated code

Comment: It looks great and it works. But do you think that is the best way to do it? that was my main question.

Comment: Yeah I think it's fine like that - if you want to write less code you can use dynamic sql and loop in each grouping bucket but that would make it alot more complex - with only 15 groups i would just write it out

Comment: okay great thank you. as far as incorporating this within in SSRS should i insert these into a temp table then just make a select to pull the dataset from that temp table?

Comment: Sure that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation for each group:

```
          SELECT COUNT (case when Value
                BETWEEN 0 AND 249999.99
                 then value else null end) AS 'Number of Plans group 1',
COUNT (case when Value
                BETWEEN 2500000  AND 3000000
                 then value else null end) AS 'Number of Plans group 2',

                  AVG (case when Value
                    BETWEEN 0 AND 249999.99
                     then value else null end) AS 'Average Value 1st group', AVG (case when Value
                    BETWEEN 2500000 AND 3000000
                     then value else null end) AS 'Average Value 2nd group'...
    from #RT1
    where instacode='s'
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `cross apply` for this:

```
SELECT v.grp, COUNT(acct) AS num_plans, AVG(value) as avg_value
FROM #RT1 t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN value >= 100 and value < 10000 THEN '$100-$10000'
                   WHEN value < 15000 THEN '$11000-$15000'
                   WHEN value < 20000 THEN '$16000-$20000'
                   WHEN value < 30000 THEN '$21000-$30000'
                   ELSE '$30000+'
              END) as grp
     ) v(grp)
GROUP BY v.grp;
```

I'm not sure what `InstaCode = 'S'` has to do with the results.  It is easy enough to add, either to the `CASE` expression or to a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @stlblues123 . . . Your question *explicitly* asks for the values in different rows.  I am surprised that you unaccepted this answer, and accepted another one that does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
Case 
    When Value between 100 and 10000 Then '100 to 10000'
    When Value between 11000 and 15000 Then '11000 to 15000'
    When Value between 16000 and 20000 Then '16000 to 20000'
    When Value between 21000 and 30000 Then '21000 to 30000'
    When Value > 30000 Then '30000+'
End as AccountValue 
  COUNT (acct) AS NumberofPlans
 , AVG (Value) AS AverageValue
FROM #RT1
WHERE Value
    BETWEEN 0 AND 249999.99
    AND InstaCode = 'S'

Group by 
Case 
 When Value between 100 and 10000 Then '100 to 10000'
 When Value between 11000 and 15000 Then '11000 to 15000'
 When Value between 16000 and 20000 Then '16000 to 20000'
 When Value between 21000 and 30000 Then '21000 to 30000'
 When Value > 30000 Then '30000+'
End
```